# How do I diplay information from a List<T> read in from XML?

Tags: winforms, list, object, xml-serialization, displayobject

So far A have created the object class module and a way to input the data which consists of different types. after the object has been created it is stored in a list these objects then can be written to an XML file or read from. The problem I am having now is displaying the data on the Form.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the fact that it's read from an XML file is irrelevant.. what you really want to know is how to display objects from a collection on a WinForm, right? There are different ways. The easiest is probably this:

1. Place a `DataGridView` on your form
2. in code, do this:

`myDataGridView.DataSource = myList; //where myList is your List<T>`